# Enthalpy: when and how does it vary?

Tags: enthalpy

[image]I have been looking for a physical explanation for entropy and enthalpy variations. An example would be the air system of a vehicle, where people say we have a strong enthalpy and entropy variations along the exhaust line, which is not the case in the fresh air line. How could that be possible?

Comment: Do you have another example for your problem? I'm not sure I really understand what your question is about by considering your given example (although I can't say exactly why - so, another example might help).

Comment: Hi @Philipp, I just updated the post and added a picture. This is a valve and the arrows are representing the fluid flow. What I still can't figure out hier regarding enthalpy/entropy, is the fact that there will be a substantial increase in the entropy accross the valve, however, the enthalpy remains substantially constant. Do you have an idea?